# Finding out what EJB view was used

Tags: java-ee-6, ejb-3.1, interceptor, ejb-jar.xml, sessioncontext

Assume I have an EJB defining two views:

- Local business,
- Remote business.

Both interfaces share the same method signatures, so it's like:

```
public interface MyBusinessCommon {
    void myMethod(Object o);
}

@Local
public interface MyBusinessLocal extends MyBusinessCommon { }

@Remote
public interface MyBusinessRemote extends MyBusinessCommon { }

@Stateless
public class MyBusinessBean implements MyBusinessLocal, MyBusinessRemote {
    public void myMethod(Object o) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

**Is there a way to figure out what EJB view was called from within the EJB itself (or its interceptor?)**

Let's say I would like to perform different authorization procedures depending on used view. Remote should be more constrained and local shouldn't.

I can invoke `SessionContext#getInvokedBusinessInterface()` but this gives me information only about the class object - not about EJB semantics of it. Plainly using reflection to check annotations presence on interfaces or bean is not enough (what about views defined in `ejb-jar.xml`?)

I doubt it is possible using straight EJB specification but perhaps there's something I missed.

If not, is it possible to get this information from the inners of an application server? (let's consider only JBoss AS 7.x, Glassfish 3.x and TomEE 1.5.1).

Comment: My gut feeling says this is just not possible in a portable way. If it is, I missed something too. A trick might be to use the convention of naming interfaces. You are already doing that; `MyBusinessLocal` ends with `Local` etc. A bit brittle, but conventions do work for e.g. JavaBeans.

Comment: Thanks Arjan. I agree - some convention might be a solution here. I guess such EJB view recognition might be only possible using server internals... If it's possible at all!

Comment: You're welcome. If you feel strongly about EJB needing this ability, then why not add a feature request for it at http://java.net/jira/browse/EJB_SPEC ?

Comment: In JBoss there's an Invocation object which has a promising isLocal() public method.  But in an interceptor you have access to an InvocationContext not an Invocation.  They are related somehow, but I don't know how.  It would be useful to try to do an isLocal() on the InvocationContext and see if the underlying object was JBoss' Invocation object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just like Arjan said - it is impossible to do just by following EJB spec.

However, in Glassfish it's quite simple to do.

All EJB interceptors accept the `InvocationContext` parameter. `InvocationContext` implementation in Glassfish is in fact `com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation` class. It has the `isLocal` field that tolds you if it's intercepting local business call (or `isRemote` for remote business calls).
You can use it e.g. as follows:

```
import com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation;

import javax.interceptor.AroundInvoke;
import javax.interceptor.Interceptor;
import javax.interceptor.InvocationContext;

@Interceptor
public class CallSourceAwareInterceptor {

    @AroundInvoke
    public Object aroundInvoke(InvocationContext ictx) throws Exception {
        boolean isLocalCall = isLocalEJBCall(ictx);

        return ictx.proceed();
    }

    boolean isLocalEJBCall(final InvocationContext ictx) {
        if (ictx instanceof EjbInvocation) {
            return ((EjbInvocation) ictx).isLocal;
        }
        else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown InvocationContext implementation.");
        }
    }
}
```

To access this `EjbInvocation` internal Glassfish class you need to add following maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.main.ejb</groupId>
    <artifactId>ejb-container</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.1-b02</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

And you might need to add following specific repository to get access to this artifact:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>maven-promoted</id>
        <url>https://maven.java.net/content/groups/promoted/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

I did a quick research (based on Richard's suggestion regarding `Invocation` object) how to achieve the same in JBoss but couldn't find answer...